# VSCode on Ubuntu not reading installed fonts

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I've recently installed VSCode version 1.29.1-1542309157 using snap on Ubuntu and I've installed Fira Code and Hack.

But it doesn't seem to work. I've restarted the OS for a few times and it still doesn't work. It will only read the fonts that have been previously installed in the system like 'Ubuntu Mono'.

Here are the pictures:
[image: VSCode font settings]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue seems to be the restrictions that snap imposes to apps installed with it. I had the exact same problem, then I uninstalled VSCode and reinstalled it with a `.deb` and everything just worked like a charm. There is an issue in the VSCode repo, in case you want to follow it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63194.

By the way, thank you so much for mentioning you had installed it with snap. That's what made it click for me.

Comment: Your solution definitely solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Just to note that this doesn't happen only in snap version. At least in my case.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. Also on ubuntu 20.04 with vscode installed via `.deb`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `Hack` with `Hack-Bold` in font family setting

That works for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).